# How to change value in property file which is part of Installation tree

Tags: install4j

I am trying to create installer for desktop application using Install4J. I have correctly selected the directories which should be part of installation tree.

In that directory, I have one property file say db.property which contains db password and url and other details. In installer, I have provided screen where user can enter all db details which should be changed in db.property file.

In installer, I want this property value setting screen first and then Installation should start. If I set Installation option first (in Installer section) and then value selection screen, it change the value but if I set value screen first and then installation then it doesn't.

My understanding is: If installer run first so value setting screen found db.properties as it got installed and change value but if value setting screen first set so it could not found property file as it is not installed yet and could not change value.

If my understanding is proper so what can be the workaround to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user for input in screens before the installation screen. Related actions, such as an action that modifies a property file, should be added to the "Installation" screen, after the "Install files" action.